# A ExampleViewModel was used after being disposed

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, state-management

Please note this is a solution for my case if you have another case share the code will be happy to help.

Code with issue:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:fake_api_provider.dart'; // Assume this is your API provider

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('API Call Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Consumer<ApiProvider>(
          builder: (context, apiProvider, _) {
            return ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Issue: API call is not canceled when navigating away
                apiProvider.fetchData();
              },
              child: Text('Fetch Data'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the "Before" code, the API call is made directly when the button is pressed, without checking if the widget is still mounted. This can lead to issues if the widget is disposed while the API call is in progress.

The solution using `context.mounted`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:fake_api_provider.dart'; // Assume this is your API provider

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('API Call Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Consumer<ApiProvider>(
          builder: (context, apiProvider, _) {
            return ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                // Solution: Check if the widget is still mounted before making the API call
                if (context.mounted) {
                  apiProvider.fetchData();
                } else {
                  print('Widget is disposed. Cannot make API call.');
                }
              },
              child: Text('Fetch Data'),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the "After" code, context.mounted is used to check if the widget is still mounted before making the API call. If the widget is disposed, the API call is not made, preventing potential errors and wasted resources.